# How to catch auth errors in Fabric and retry?

Tags: python, fabric

I have two usernames and corresponding passwords that I use to admin my servers, is there a way to have my fab scripts/modules, use one and then the second if the first one failed, with out having to maintain a full list of credentials for each host or even group of them.

I see no way in the docs to doa try/except around run() or similar...

Answer (score 1):

`run` and other commands raise SystemExit

```
from fabric.api import run,cd,put,sudo,settings

def do_stuff():
    run('ls derp')

try:
    with(settings(host_string='%s@localhost' % first_user,password = first_password)):
        do_stuff()
except SystemExit:
    with(settings(host_string='%s@localhost' % second_user,password = second_password)):
        do_stuff()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  To do this though, I'd have to wrap every call in a `try/except` block.  Is there any way in the Fabric settings to do this or somewhere top-level, similar to how you can set `env.warn_only`?

Comment: jdotjdot, you should only have to wrap every call in a try/except, if every call needs to try two passwords, right?

Comment: This actually wasn't my SO question; I had something similar but not quite this use case.