# Get Fabric to email me when aborting

Tags: python, error-handling, fabric

I'm using Fabric to manage remote deployment of my blog that uses the static site generator Pelican.  Whenever I drop a new file in Dropbox, I use Dropbox webhooks to launch a series of tasks that are on a Heroku server.   The tasks are managed using Fabric.

Because this is all done remotely, I currently have to manually inspect the logs whenever I realize that something went wrong.  I'd like Fabric to email me whenever it aborts due to an error.

How can I catch a Fabric abort so that I can have it send me an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) exception thrown by a failing task and then send an email in the exception handling block.

See also relevant topics:

- [How to catch auth errors in Fabric and retry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481742/how-to-catch-auth-errors-in-fabric-and-retry)
- [How to continue a task when Fabric receives an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876936/how-to-continue-a-task-when-fabric-receives-an-error)

Comment: hanks, this is helpful. To do this though, I'd have to wrap every call in a `try/except` block or create one "run everything" function in a `try/except` block. Is there any way in the Fabric settings to do this or somewhere top-level, similar to how you can set `env.warn_only`?

Comment: @jdotjdot I'd wrap every task into `try/except` decorator, see for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386592/repetitive-try-and-except-clauses.

Comment: Ah--great idea.  Thanks; hadn't thought of that.